# WP7 ApplicationIdleDetectionMode and EmailComposeTask/CameraCaptureTask/PhotoChooserTask

Tags: windows-phone-7, crash

I'm trying to find solution crash in this WP7 app:

1. Create new WP7 app.
2. Allow app to run in locked screen:

   ```
    // in App()
   PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
   ```
3. In MainPage place button
4. Add button code, which run CameraCaptureTask:

   ```
   var cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureTask();
   cameraCapture.Completed += cameraCapture_Completed;
   cameraCaptureTask.Show();
   ```
5. Lock screen with hardware button.
6. Unlock screen - CRASH :-(

Exception:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException - "0x8000ffff"
```

StackTrace:

```
    at Microsoft.Phone.Execution.NativeEmInterop.NotifyFullObscurityChanged(Boolean isObscured)
    at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.OnFullObscurityChanged(Object sender, LockStateChangeEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.ShellPageManager.ShellPageCallback_OnLockStateChange(Object source, LockStateChangeEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.ShellPageCallback.FireOnLockStateChange(Boolean fLocked)
```

It crashes in real hardware (Samsung Omnia W) - no emulator.
I did tested this with EmailComposeTask/CameraCaptureTask/PhotoChooserTask - always crashes.

**EDIT:**

Steps to crach app:

1. Project template: Windows Phone Application
2. Target Windows Phone OS Version: Windows Phone OS 7.1

App.xaml.cs - just one line added, at then end of App constructor:

```
    [...]
    public App()
    {
        UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializePhoneApplication();

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
        }

        PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
    }
    [...]
```

MainPage.xaml, added button:

```
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="361,262,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs - methods added:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhotoChooserTask objPhotoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
        objPhotoChooser.Completed += objPhotoChooser_Completed;
        objPhotoChooser.Show();
    }

    private void objPhotoChooser_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
    }
```

Connect your phone, compile and deploy program to phone, disconnect phone (PhotoChooserTask do not work with Zune). Run program in Your device, click 'button', lock screen with hardware button, then unlock it - crashes and closes program.
You can use WPConnect instead of Zune to debug this.

Comment: Can you post a full, minimal, repro so we can see how you're using the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on WP8 device (Lumia 820 Developer edition) and works ok. Only problem I can see is that when you unlock device you are not getting back to launcher screen but to app screen. I assume, that issue is connected with different approarch in low level implementation of Launchers on WP7 and WP8.

Comment: Thanks Maciek. In WP7 if you dont set IdleDetectionMode.Disabled it also goes back to app screen. Maybe 7.8 will fix crashing when IdleDetectionMode.Disabled is set.